# What does "internal" mean in windbg "!heap -a" output

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps

I am using windbg command "!heap -a " to check the memory status, and get the following results.

what does internal mean at the end of this entry "00d168f0: 03d20 . 06b48 [101] - busy (6b40) Internal"?

```
Heap entries for Segment00 in Heap 00d10000
     address: psize . size  flags   state (requested size)
    00d10000: 00000 . 00588 [101] - busy (587)
    00d10588: 00588 . 00240 [101] - busy (23f)
    00d107c8: 00240 . 00220 [101] - busy (214)
    00d109e8: 00220 . 00808 [101] - busy (800)
    00d111f0: 00808 . 00060 [101] - busy (56)

    ...

    00d12b10: 00020 . 00040 [101] - busy (35)
    00d12b50: 00040 . 00040 [101] - busy (35)
    00d12b90: 00040 . 00020 [101] - busy (12)
    00d12bb0: 00020 . 00020 [101] - busy (18)
    00d12bd0: 00020 . 03d20 [101] - busy (3d1f)
    00d168f0: 03d20 . 06b48 [101] - busy (6b40) Internal 
    00d1d438: 06b48 . 00050 [101] - busy (46)
    00d1d488: 00050 . 00040 [101] - busy (34)
    00d1d4c8: 00040 . 00800 [101] - busy (7f8) Internal 
    00d1dcc8: 00800 . 00400 [101] - busy (3f8) Internal 
    00d1e0c8: 00400 . 00010 [101] - busy (4)
    00d1e0d8: 00010 . 00010 [101] - busy (4)
```

Comment: "This question already has an answer here:

    What's the meaning of “Internal” in “!heap -h” output in windbg? 1 answer" -- The answer there did not clearly answer the question.